# SQL Statement "Update" Color in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

When we use SQL Server 2008 to write SQL statement using the keyword `update`, it was colored in `blue`:

[image]

But when we write the same SQL in SQL Server 2014, it's in `magenta`:

[image]

And as we know, the magenta color in the SQL Server is normally not for keywords, but for `built-int functions`, or `datepart` (and some others):

[image]

*(in the example above, `Datename` and `getdate` are built-in `functions` while `day` and `week` are `datepart`)*

But the `select`, `create`, `insert`, and `delete` keywords are all consistently `blue` in the SQL Server:

[image]

What's the reason behind this change (is `update` a `function` now)? Is there any way to change the `update` color back to `blue` in SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 3):

It is a Trigger function, you can use it like UPDATE(ColumnName) and this will return true or false if you updated that coulmn.

[MSDN Update Function()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx)

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE
>   attempt was made on a specified column of a table or view. UPDATE() is
>   used anywhere inside the body of a Transact-SQL INSERT or UPDATE
>   trigger to test whether the trigger should execute certain actions.